# datatables pagination number show

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables, yadcf

I want to add pagination by numbers not previous & next only button , I don't know where is the problem it's cdn or code in jquery here is 
  i work on it ,i want the pagination to be like the simple_numbers pagination

```
<https://www.codepen.io/HusseinZaki/pen/ddLwwq>?
```

Comment: https://www.codepen.io/HusseinZaki/pen/ddLwwq

Comment: Did you try setting pagingType? The codepen is tooooo huge that I felt asking whether you set pagingType or not rather than verifying it in codepen

Comment: I did it make the table not working at all

Comment: hmm.. seeing the html, looks like you did a lot and lots of customization on top of datatable.

Comment: So ,can you help me

Comment: will give it a try.. will it be possible to post only needed code among the entire code u have?

Comment: Sorry, no i can’t make it

Comment: @G_S  can you try to help me

Comment: trying to understand what the code contains.

Comment: @G_S when I tried to but it in the code between the columns it make the table broke

Comment: Yes, this datatable is being represented in a different way(atleast for me) than the traditional way of writing it

Comment: @G_S can you still help me

Comment: @G_S i tried this way `$('#data').dataTable( {
  "pagingType": "full_numbers"
} ); ` and it failed

Comment: I dont think your way of configuring datatables is direct. I have to check it. I can't assure i will be giving you a solution. but lets hope so

Comment: @G_S i am waiting for you

Comment: finally.. able to see whats going on

Comment: @G_S , so can you help me please

Comment: added answer. check it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the datatables version you are using is not supporting paging properly.

changed datatables cdn to https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js (at this time of writing this answer, this is the cdn provided by datatables)

and changed your datatable line to
 `$('#data').dataTable({"pagingType": "full_numbers"})`

Give it a try.

Comment: yes,it works but now when i click on the filter icon on the left it disappear

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for it? I am unable to see any issue

Comment: test it in the codepen, this the new one after i added your code https://codepen.io/HusseinZaki/pen/ddLwwq

Comment: Its not with the line that we added just now. There is something else. I removed the line and its still disappearing   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddEYPo

Comment: in the link you sent it the number is shown but the filter icon is not working as suppose to work

Comment: I am not sure about the filter icon functionality. Provide a working datatable code that you have and then we can see it by adding pagination

Comment: https://codepen.io/HusseinZaki/pen/mXYeMm it is the new link , and it is working now

Comment: i wonder why it is not working with `simple_numbers` it is working only with ` full_numbers`

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYNpmX its working. i am using https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js as my datatable cdn

Comment: look at my code without adding this cdn with adding the old one https://codepen.io/HusseinZaki/pen/mXYeMm the filter is working in yours  filter is not working

Comment: There is some custom code that you might be needed to change in your application. but not sure still

Comment: can you try to fix it

Comment: no i am not aware of the logic that you are doing. Sorry about this